# The return type 'num' isn't a 'T', as required by the closure's context

Tags: dart

I've defined an extension:

```dart
extension MyIterable<T extends num> on Iterable<T> {
  T sum() => reduce((v, e) => v + e); // Error
}
```

Why is `v + e` not considered `T`, why is there an error?

> The return type 'num' isn't a 'T', as required by the closure's context.

I'm using it in the `main`:

```dart
void main() {
  int a = MyIterable<int>([1, 2]).sum();
  double b = MyIterable<double>([1.0, 2]).sum();
  num c = MyIterable<num>([1.0, 2]).sum();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `v` and `e` are statically known to be `T`, which is some subtype of `num`, the exact subtype isn't known, so `v + e` is only statically known to conform to `num.operator+`.  Consequently, the result is `num` (the base type), not necessarily a `T` (the more specific subtype).

In this case, I think you'll probably need to add an `as T` explicit cast.

Comment: As you said "the result is num (the base type), not necessarily a T (the more specific subtype)" -- but in reality, the result is always going to be a type of `T` (at least in this particular case).

Comment: @iDecode Yes, but the compiler and analyzer don't know that.  That's also why an `as T` cast would be safe. (And the only reason why the result would always be a `T` is because `num` is not allowed to be extended by custom classes.)